# Confused about return in Functions

Tags: python

Ok, I'm having trouble with my very first program. If you look down to the two functions, what I want is for if the "cur" value is NOT between  the min and max, for it to change the Target variable to "0" so I can use it latter in the program... But it doesn't seem to do it... Am I using "return" wrong? Basically, the functions need to turn `target` from `1` to `0`, so that `ri_fit` changes to 0, so that my final `if` thingys trigger...

Sorry for the terrible code, I've only just begun!

```
#Clearance calculator
#clearances are in clearances.txt

targets = open("clearances.txt", "r")
lines = targets.readlines()   #get target clearances from file

in_min_target = float(lines[2])     #minimum intake clearance
in_max_target = float(lines[4])     #maximum intake clearance

ex_min_target = float(lines[8])    #miminum exhaust clearances
ex_max_target = float(lines[10])   #maximum exhaust clearances
targets.close

target_intake = (in_min_target + in_max_target) / 2     #find the ideal intake
target_exhaust = (ex_min_target + ex_max_target) / 2    #find the ideal exhaust

print "Intake Min: ", in_min_target
print "Intake Max: ", in_max_target
print "Exhaust Min: ", ex_min_target
print "Exhaust Max: ", ex_max_target
print """Target intake: %r
Target Exhaust: %r""" % (target_intake, target_exhaust)

print""
print "Enter current RIGHT side Intake clearance"
cur_r_in = float(raw_input(">"))
print ""
print "Enter current RIGHT side Exhaust clearance"
cur_r_ex = float(raw_input(">"))
print ""
print "Enter current LEFT side Intake clearance"
cur_l_in = float(raw_input(">"))
print ""
print "Enter current LEFT side Exhaust clearance"
cur_l_ex = float(raw_input(">"))


target = 1

def in_range(min, max, cur, valve, target):  #figures if intake valves are correct
    if min <= cur <= max:
        print "%r is in range." % valve
        target=1

    else:
        print "%r is OUT OF RANGE." %valve
        target=0

    return target

def ex_range(min, max, cur, valve, target):   #figures if exhaust valves are correct
    if min <= cur <= max:
        print "%r is in range." % valve
        target=1

    else:
        print "%r is OUT OF RANGE." %valve
        target=0
    return target


ri_fit = 1
re_fit = 1        #Assumes all valves are right, until further notice...
li_fit = 1
le_fit = 1

valve = "Right Intake"
print in_range(in_min_target, in_max_target, cur_r_in, valve, target)
print target
if target == 0:
    ri_fit = 0


print ""

valve = "Right Exhaust"
print ex_range(ex_min_target, ex_max_target, cur_r_ex, valve, target)

print ""

valve = "Left Intake"
print in_range(in_min_target, in_max_target, cur_l_in, valve, target)

print ""

valve = "Left Exhaust"
print ex_range(ex_min_target, ex_max_target, cur_l_ex, valve, target)

print ri_fit

if ri_fit==0:
    print "Right intake is out of range."
    print "Enter current right intake shim size."
    ri_cur_shim = int(raw_input(">"))

if re_fit==0:
    print "Right exhaust is out of range."
    print "Enter current right exhaust shim size."
    re_cur_shim = int(raw_input(">"))

if li_fit==0:
    print "Right intake is out of range."
    print "Enter current right intake shim size."
    li_cur_shim = int(raw_input(">"))

if le_fit==0:
    print "Right exhaust is out of range."
    print "Enter current right exhaust shim size."
    le_cur_shim = int(raw_input(">"))
```

Comment: What's the difference between your two methods?  The code for both looks exactly the same.

Comment: Thank you all very much for your help. It now seems to work. It's really my fault for trying to do this before I really know what I'm doing! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue lies in that you are passing `target` as a value, not as a reference. Within your functions, you should drop the `target` parameter, and instead write:

```
def ex_range(min, max, cur, valve):
    global target
    # ...
    # rest of your code
```

This way, the interpreter identifies that you're trying to set the global `target` variable, and not a local instance.

Otherwise, you could do something like:

```
def in_range(min, max, cur, valve):  #figures if intake valves are correct
    if min <= cur <= max:
        print "%r is in range." % valve
        return 1

    else:
        print "%r is OUT OF RANGE." %valve
        return 0

target = in_range(...) # fill in args
print target
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them) related question.

Answer (score 2):

When you assign to target inside one of your functions, you are replacing the value of the parameter named target in there, and not touching the global one.  So if you want your functions to assign to the global target, you can't define a new target in the function.

But if you don't want to change your functions, you can use the fact that return returns  a value (which you seem to understand, since you print it).  If instead of printing it, you assigned it to target, then you'd get the value you want where you want it, and your function will work no matter where the value computed is ultimately destined to go.

Answer (score 1):

`return` returns a value from a function. You can store the result in a variable.

In your code, you're trying to pass `target` as a parameter and then set its value, but since integers are immutable, you won't be able to change `target` from within your function.

In your case, I'd change your code to something like this:

```
def ex_range(min, max, cur, valve):  # You don't need `target` here
    if min <= cur <= max:
        print "%r is in range." % valve
        target=1

    else:
        print "%r is OUT OF RANGE." %valve
        target=0
    return target

target = ex_range(...)  # Store the results in a variable
```

Better yet, use a boolean:

```
def ex_range(min, max, cur, valve):  # You don't need `target` here
    if min <= cur <= max:
        print "%r is in range." % valve
        return True

    else:
        print "%r is OUT OF RANGE." %valve
        return False
```

Comment: Why have the function (in the first version) assign to target AND return that value, to have the caller redundantly assign it to target?

Comment: @ScottHunter: `target` is within the function's scope, not the global scope, so it's just a matter of using two return statements versus one.

Comment: Ok, in the second example, what gets returned as `True` or `False`? How can I use that?

Comment: @Demonic: `True` and `False` are keywords. You used `1` and `0`, but usually people use `True` and `False` instead, as they're more readable.

Comment: @Demonic: In your original code, `target=1` just set `target` to `1`. At the end of the function, you called `return target` to return the value of `target` from your function. `target` doesn't do anything other than hold the value of `1` or `0`. Since you `return` the value in the end, you can just skip the `target = ...` part and `return` the results immediately.

Comment: Ah, Ok. Well, I've turned "target" into a global value, so that seems to fix it. But I will keep your method in mind for next time, too! Thanks!

Comment: @Demonic: Personally, I don't suggest you use globals for this. There's really no reason to.

Comment: @Blender, ok, but is there a good reason NOT to? I'm not being difficult, just honestly curious...

Answer (score 1):

First, I guess you need `()` after `close`:

```
target.close()
```

Second:
`in_range` and `ex_range` are exactly the same!

Third, anyway it is OK and so runs correctly:

```
in_range(1,10,7,'Right Intake',1)
in_range(1,10,17,'Right Intake',1)
```

output:

```
>>> 'Right Intake' is in range.
>>> 'Right Intake' is OUT OF RANGE.
```

So, it may be the arguments you are passing to functions are **not OK**! Check if you are reading them correctly from file.

Finally, avoid using `min`, `max` as arguments as they are `built-in` Python functions.